# CSS: нужно чтобы при наведении мыши на один элемент изменялось свойство другого элемента

Tags: css3, html, css, javascript

Как средствами CSS сделать так, чтобы при наведении мыши на один элемент изменялось свойство другого элемента? Если возможно, желательно CSS, если нет -- то на JS.

Comment: На JS работает только с id ?
Если да, то такой вариант не катит, т.к работает только с одним элементом списка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

function smena()

{

var elem.document.getElementById("tag");
elem.setAttribute("id", "tag2"); //сменить атрибут
elem.firstChild.nodeValue="другой текст";

}

</script>

<h1 onClick="smena()">Изменить</h1>

<p id="tag">текст</p>
```

Answer (score 8):

Можно и через CSS3.
Используя терминологию предыдущего ответа, код будет примерно таким:

```
ЦЕЛЬ:hover ~ ЖЕРТВА {
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s 0.3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s 0.3s ease-in;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index: 2106;
}
```

В фигурных скобках прописываем параметры анимации изменения и изменяемые свойства.
Есть только два условия, при которых этот способ будет работать:

1. ЦЕЛЬ и ЖЕРТВА должны быть братьями (то есть иметь общий родительский элемент).
2. ЖЕРТВА в коде должна быть ниже ЦЕЛИ.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
ЦЕЛЬ.onmouseover = function(){ЖЕРТВА.style.СВОЙСТВО='РЕЗУЛЬТАТ'};
ЦЕЛЬ.onmouseout = function(){ЖЕРТВА.style.СВОЙСТВО=''};
</script>
```

Через CSS нельзя. А в скрипте - первая строчка - присваивает свойство при наведении, вторая - возвращает как было, потому кавычки должны остаться пустыми.
Вместо "ЦЕЛЬ" подставь id элемента, на который наводишь мышь, вместо "ЖЕРТВА" - id того, который должен измениться.

Если CSS-свойство состоит из одного слова, так его и дописываешь
вместо "СВОЙСТВО".

Если из двух, например `background-color, vertical-align`, то меняешь на формат
backgroundColor
verticalAlign

То есть, первое слово без изменений, тире убираешь и первую букву второго слова пишешь в верхнем регистре. Если слов больше - так же поступаешь с продолжением.
вот пример:

```
<input type='button' value='у меня id=one'  id='one'/>
<input type='button' value='а у меня id=two'  id='two'/>
<script>
one.onmouseover = function(){two.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'};
one.onmouseout = function(){two.style.backgroundColor = ''};
</script>
```

Comment: В CSS есть селектор `~` для выбора сестринских элементов, так что вы заблуждаетесь относительно невозможности реализации данного функционала средствами CSS. Посмотрите на ответ пользователя @TheDoctor

Answer (score 1):

> Как средствами CSS сделать так, чтобы при наведении мыши на один элемент изменялось свойство другого элемента?

Это возможно для некоторых частных случаев:

```
1. Вложенный элемент:
   .smth:hover .dest {}

2. Непосредственно следующий или один из следующих элементов:
   .smth:hover + .dest {}
   .smth:hover ~ .dest {}

3. Внутри следующего или одного из следующих
   .smth:hover + .smth-else .dest {}
   .smth:hover ~ .smth-else .dest {}
```

В остальных случаях вроде нельзя. Стоит попробовать привести разметку к одному из перечисленных вариантов и воспользоваться соответствующим кодом.

Вот если бы требование было на клик, а не на наведение, то можно было бы чекбоксы в корень бросить и воспользоваться лейблами.

Answer (score 0):

Сам не профи, но думается мне можно, если есть вложенность, как то так:

```
<div id="a">
  <p>Меняюсь</p>
</div>

 #a:hover p{
 font-size: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Вложенности нет.

Comment: тогда наверно через JS или пусть меня поправят опытные разработчики

Comment: если что то добавьте в <p id="b"> и проверьте
 <script>
   document.getElementById('a').onmouseover = fun;
   function fun(){
      document.getElementById('b').style.backgroundColor="red";
   }
 </script>