# Заменить jquery .hover() на чистый css

Tags: jquery, css

```
<script>
    $(".class").hover(
            function () {
                $('.class').css('opacity', '0.5');
            }, function () {
                $('.class').css('opacity', '1');
            }
    );
</script>
```

Это же нужно написать только с помощью css.
Существует ли решение данного вопроса без jquery?

Answer (score 4):

```
.class{
   opacity:1;
}
.class:hover{
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: <script>
    $(".classBtn").hover(
            function () {
                $('.classImg').css('opacity', '0.5');
            }, function () {
                $('.classImg').css('opacity', '1');
            }
    );
</script>
Кнопка под картинкой.

Comment: А для такого сценария попробуй реализовать как в статье http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/338211/204549